# how to encrypt data in configurations file other then web.config using aspnet_regiis

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, aspnet-regiis.exe

In a MVC project we have a web.config file and multiple config files other then that.

I was able to encrypt connection string in web.config using aspnet_regiis. Can you pleased guide how I can encrypt data in configuration files other then web.config using aspnet_regiis ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't encrypt other files. You can only encrypt `web.config` or, if the `-pkm` switch is provided, the `machine.config` file.